# Negative and positive values matching and update

Tags: sql-server

I have a large data set containing transactional data. The data includes credit notes which are essentially 'returned' goods. To offset the positive value, each of these returns has an equal negative entry.

I am looking for an sql query to identify and flag ("Y") the set of records which neutralize each other in order to exclude subset instead of deleting the data.

My data contains an ID column.

---

Schema available;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b0f1

Comment: Why are the numeric columns stored are varchar?

Comment: And which column are you expecting to be neutralized? What output do you expect from your example data?

Comment: For fiddle only, RCV_Total

Expecting a flag where negative row matches positive row

Comment: Considering that the values *are* a `varchar`, then you can't `SUM` them. If you fix your design, this'll be trivial, as the `SUM` of `10` and `-10` is `0`. On the other had, the `SUM` of `'10'` and `'-10'` is an error.

Comment: *"For fiddle only"* **why**? If you're columns aren't a `varchar`, why tell us they *are*? Please amend your fiddle so that we have representative data and datatypes.

Comment: you mean 1234 has 3 rows. 10, 30 and -10. you want to set Y against -10 only or both 10 and -10?

Comment: Both for -10 and 10 to enable me to exclude the transaction as a whole

Comment: If there are two 10s and two -10s, how do you match a 10 with a -10? Also, is there an column that indicates the order of transactions?

Comment: what if you sell 3 of product 1234, and then get 2 returns?  How would you know which of the transactions were 'returned'?

Comment: Because there is no ordering on this table, what you are asking is impossible. For example, what happens if there are 2 orders for 10, then a single 10 return - which order does that return apply to?

Comment: in case of ('1235','2','12','-24') it will be difficult to determine set off with which ('1235','2','12','24')

Comment: Indeed... It would be better if there was a Order Number orsomething to better tie things together. The best I could come up with was this:
`select * from Data_FY19 T1
inner join Data_FY19 T2 
  on T1.Product_Code = T2.Product_Code 
    and T1.RCV_Total = ABS(T2.RCV_Total) 
    and T1.RCV_Total + T2.RCV_Total = 0
`
But even that is a bit janky as 1235 is repeated incorrectly because of the double match.

Comment: @Ferdi did you try any solution?

Comment: My predicament exactly - the system does not cater for a reverse matching transaction number. I have no way of reconciling a specific transaction with its return other than product code and transaction amount (product price * quantity bought/returned).

My hope is, however, that these should reconcile at an aggregated level at least. I know this question might not be a coding problem in the strictest sense.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may work as per your expectation but still I am working on creating double temp table. and also you need to have a primary ID in main table to update the same as this will just show result in temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data_FY19]
(
    [Product_Code] [VARCHAR](150) NULL,
    [RCV_Quantity] DECIMAL(12, 2) NULL,
    [RCV_Unit_Cost] DECIMAL(12, 2) NULL,
    [RCV_Total] DECIMAL(12, 2) NULL,
    [Return_Flag] [VARCHAR](150) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Data_FY19]
(
    [Product_Code],
    [RCV_Quantity],
    [RCV_Unit_Cost],
    [RCV_Total]
)
VALUES
('1234', '1', '10', '10'),
('1235', '2', '12', '24'),
('1236', '2', '15', '30'),
('1237', '1', '20', '20'),
('1238', '2', '15', '30'),
('1239', '3', '10', '30'),
('1240', '2', '20', '40'),
('1236', '4', '15', '60'),
('1234', '3', '10', '30'),
('1239', '-3', '10', '-30'),
('1236', '-2', '15', '-30'),
('1234', '-1', '10', '-10'),
('1237', '-1', '20', '-20'),
('1235', '-2', '12', '-24'),
('1235', '2', '12', '24');




SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS rwno,
       *
INTO #Data_FY19
FROM Data_FY19;



SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Code ORDER BY rwno ASC) AS rn
INTO #maxOfeach
FROM #Data_FY19;

--;WITH maxofeach AS
--()


UPDATE d1
SET Return_Flag = 'Y'
FROM #Data_FY19 d1
    INNER JOIN #Data_FY19 d2
        ON d1.Product_Code = d2.Product_Code
WHERE d1.rwno <> d2.rwno
      AND d1.RCV_Total = ABS(d2.RCV_Total)
      AND d1.RCV_Total + d2.RCV_Total = 0
      AND d1.rwno IN
          (
              SELECT rwno
              FROM #maxOfeach m
              WHERE m.rn = 1
                    AND m.Product_Code = d1.Product_Code
          );

SELECT *
FROM #Data_FY19;

UPDATE d2
SET Return_Flag = 'Y'
FROM #Data_FY19 d1
    INNER JOIN #Data_FY19 d2
        ON d1.Product_Code = d2.Product_Code
WHERE d1.rwno <> d2.rwno
      AND d1.RCV_Total = ABS(d2.RCV_Total)
      AND d1.RCV_Total + d2.RCV_Total = 0
      AND d1.rwno IN
          (
              SELECT rwno
              FROM #maxOfeach m
              WHERE m.rn = 1
                    AND m.Product_Code = d1.Product_Code
          );

SELECT *
FROM #Data_FY19;

DROP TABLE #Data_FY19;
DROP TABLE #maxOfeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the records to exclude, try

```
With Ranker AS 
(SELECT *, 
     row_number() 
             OVER (
                     PARTITION BY Product_Code, RCV_Quantity, RCV_Unit_Cost, RCV_Total 
                     ORDER BY RCV_Total ASC
                   ) AS pos_rank,
     row_number() 
             OVER (
                     PARTITION BY Product_Code, RCV_Quantity, RCV_Unit_Cost, RCV_Total 
                     ORDER BY RCV_Total DESC
                   ) AS neg_rank
       FROM [dbo].[Data_FY19]
)
select r1.*, r2.* from Ranker r1 JOIN Ranker r2 on r1.RCV_Total >0 
                                     AND r2.RCV_Total <0 
                                     AND r1.pos_rank = r2.neg_rank
                                     AND r1.Product_Code = r2.Product_Code 
                                     AND r1.RCV_Quantity = -1* r2.RCV_Quantity
                                     AND r1.RCV_Unit_Cost = r2.RCV_Unit_Cost
                                     AND r1.RCV_Total = -1* r2.RCV_Total
```